# how to return a boolean instead of a relationship in a cypher return projection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to return a boolean true|false in the select/return statement of a neo4j cypher query, rather than returning the relationship.

for example

```
START me = node:node_auto_index(Uname="test")
MATCH me-[f?:Favorite]->items
return items.Title, f as isFavorite;
```

How do have isFavorite return as a bool rather than as an entire relationship object?  Is there an isExists() function?

Should I just do it as:

```
return count(f) > 0 as isFavorite
```

Note: I've deleted the neo4jclient question as this is a more succint question as is actually a bit more general then the other one.

Comment: you can do `return not(not(count(f) > 0)) as isFavorite`

Comment: is doing the double not  more efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For newer neo4j (I'm using 2.1.2) the query could look like this (I'll skip the index part):

```
OPTIONAL MATCH me-[f:Favorite]->items
RETURN items.Title, f IS NOT NULL as isFavorite;
```

Comment: Thanks zaboco, using the IS NOT NULL component also works on 3.5.x